# Send Stripe Notification when Credit Card is about to expire

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

Is there a way in Stripe to automatically send an email to a customer when their credit card is about to expire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the sense you're looking for the answer is likely no.  If you're willing to pay for it, something like [Stunning](https://bestunning.net/) can do this for you.  Otherwise I think you'd need to setup something on your system to periodically cycle through your customer database and ping Stripe about the status of any credit cards they have on file to see if any are expiring soon.

Answer (score 21):

Great news! There shouldn't be a need to notify the customer about expiration dates (or even replacement cards). Stripe's system automatically handles these changes with [Smarter saved cards](https://stripe.com/blog/smarter-saved-cards):

> Now, when you save a customer with Stripe, their card will continue to work even if the physical card gets replaced by the bank. Stripe works directly with card networks so that your customers can continue using your service without interruption.

This feature started in early 2015, according to the article's date of 2015-01-21.

Answer (score 2):

As Tyler mentioned, [Stripe's Card Updater](https://stripe.com/blog/smarter-saved-cards) has changed the game when it comes to expired cards.

However, it won't automatically catch 100% of expiring cards. At best, maybe around 70%, as some international territories and card issuers are not yet covered.

Even so, this has made pre-dunning emails (notifying customers before their card expires) obsolete in the best case, and actively harmful in the worst case...triggering "payment problem" notifications to customers who will never actually have a payment problem. These notifications can burden support teams and cause unnecessary customer involvement & confusion.

If you decide not to send pre-dunning emails (we don't), you definitely do need to send dunning emails (when payments actually do fail) which will catch actual, expired cards missed by Card Updater, as well as other kinds of failures that couldn't have been caught by Card Updater.

This [Stripe dunning checklist](https://churnbuster.io/blog/dunning-to-reduce-payment-churn/) is useful in building the optimal system on top of Stripe.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, now in stripe settings, you could set up the simple reminder email before the card expiration. It's inside `Settings -> Prevent failed payments`

Comment: FYI you can find this under `Settings > Subscriptions and emails > ...`

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such way. Stunning as mentioned by Dhaulagiri sure is a solution but its not free.

A simple alternative is:

1. When taking the card info by the users for the first time, add the
   field for expiry date (stripe provides validation for it too).
2. Keep checking the card's expiry date at regular intervals (say
   monthly or at the time of charging).
3. If the card is about to expire (in say a month or by the time of
   next charge) handle that case to notify your customer.